# getting null pointer when reading the properties file

Tags: java, properties

when reading the properties file, iam getting `nullpointer` exception.

```
faceConfig.load(ReadPropertyFile.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resources/faces.properties"));
```

below is the path of properties file `facedetections/src/main/resources/faces.properties`

i tried in different combinations as my class file that reads in below path `/facedetections/src/main/java/com/facial/facedetection/utils/ReadPropertyFile.java`

combinations are `../../../../../resource/faces.properties` , `/resource/faces.properties` and

```
../../../resource/faces.properties
```

Please suggest what is the correct path i can provide for this.

**Edit :**
I extracted the war file and providing its path below.
[image: war extraction]

Comment: what is the path of class in which you are reading this?

Comment: @GV /facedetections/src/main/java/com/facial/facedetection/utils/ReadPropertyFile.java

Comment: Have you tried just `/faces.properties`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer its not working

Comment: Can you verify that the file exists in the generated Jar file?

Comment: Where is it *in the WAR file?*

Comment: @EJP please find the screenshot attached above which explains the war file strutcture

Comment: Your screenshot is almost illegible, but the entire structure under WEB-INF looks wrong. Where are the `classes` and `lib` directories? The `.properties` file should be in the WEB-INF/classes folder, and so should the `com` directory.

Answer (score 2):

looks your property file under class folder not in resource.
as your screen shot cant find resource folder under class folder.

So just use

```
 ReadPropertyFile.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("faces.properties")
```

Answer (score 0):

The path is relative to the point where the object (`.class`) files are located.  Are you sure you have configured your build/test tool to copy the resource file into that structure?  Exactly where?  That's what counts, not the position of the sources.

Additionally, my understanding is that `getResourceAsStream()` of most `ClassLoaders` do not support `..` notation.

The position where your resource file is currently located is out of reach of the `ClassLoader`.  If you move your file to `/facedetections/src/main/java/resources/faces.properties`, then you will be able to use the current code

```
getResourceAsStream("resources/faces.properties")
```

I'm making assumptions about your environment.  In particular, this is entirely dependent on classloaders.  If this doesn't help, please provide **object** file location, not sources (unless it is the same, but state it).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is unlikely that you get a NPE when the file is not found I assume that `faceConfig` is `null` when you execute that line.